# CORS error in flask even after using flask-cors

Tags: javascript, python, flask, cors, flask-cors

I start learning some `back-end` development with `Flask` but when I try to make a route that returns json data but it throws `CORS ERROR`, for tunneling I use `ngrok`

main.py

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)

CORS(app)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello'

@app.route('/test')
def about():
    return jsonify({'key_one':'some testing value'})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

and here is javascript and html

```
console.log("hello");

fetch("https://link.ngrok.io/test")
  .then((x) => x.json())
  .then((r) => console.log(r))
  .catch((e) => console.log(e));
```

the html are just for holding the `JS` file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script defer src='main.js' >
      
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

and here an image for the output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You Flask code seems correct. It think the error happens because your `ngork` server doesn't allow cors request. If it allows then I recommend to use `axios` package instead built-in `fetch`.

Comment: What would `axios` change?

Comment: @jaaba  It can be used to make AJAX requests to a remote server and handle the responses in a more flexible way than the built-in fetch API.

Comment: How would handling the response in a more flexible way help here? The request can't be sent. There is no response.

Comment: I think this might help https://gist.github.com/magnunleno/8dad91f133a22322250d6cb609792597